# PHP class getting error when using return

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
public function lockFields($lockFieldsDB, $lockValue) {
    if($lockFieldsDB == $lockValue){
        $lockInputField = 'readonly="readonly"';
        $lockSelectField = 'disabled = "disabled"';
        $lockImage = '<img title="Locked field" src="http://www.trustive.com/static/images/padlock_icon.png">';
    }
    else {
        $lockInputField = null;
        $lockSelectField = null;
        $lockImage = null;
    }
    return [$lockInputField, $lockSelectField, $lockImage];
}
```

The code used to work fine, but my host made some maintenance to his server and it seems that I am getting the following error in my php `syntax error, unexpected '['` This refers to `return [$lockInputField, $lockSelectField, $lockImage];`

I can't seem to understand why it worked and now it doesn't after the update

Comment: Need PHP >= 5.4.0 for `[]` syntax.

Comment: Mine is `5.4.24` are you saying my host degraded my version of php?

Comment: Must have.  `[]` array syntax was added in 5.4.0.  Check `phpinfo()`.

Comment: how does you check php version?

Comment: Try `return array($lockInputField, $lockSelectField, $lockImage);` if it works with no errors, *then yeah...* they've done something to the server.

Comment: `echo phpversion();` or `PHP_VERSION`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Now I am getting `syntax error, unexpected ','`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I checked from my cpanel

Comment: @user3758251 On which line do you get the new error

Comment: @Rizier123 I got the error for ` return [$lockInputField, $lockSelectField, $lockImage];`

Comment: @Fred-ii- provided the correct return value but I had to down vote the question because Its vague to me. What do you expect to happen on your screen instead of the syntax error message? Also, the values of the function parameters need to be checked.

Try creating a new PHP script containing `function lockFields($lockFieldsDB, $lockValue) {echo $lockFieldsDB." ".$lockValue;}` and execute it instead of what you have and see if the values being displayed look normal. If not, then check other PHP scripts that are calling this one.

Comment: @Mike that is too harsh to downvote a questions. I'm only a beginner. I got the reply below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your server, but you might as well just do it the correct way.

Change this.

```
return [$lockInputField, $lockSelectField, $lockImage];
```

To this

```
return array($lockInputField, $lockSelectField, $lockImage);
```

Comment: @user3758251 [So did this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28726784/php-class-getting-error-when-using-return?noredirect=1#comment45740131_28726784) a 1/2 hour prior to this comment and 20 mins. prior to this answer. So, what's so different about this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I must have missed the array. My bad.

Comment: @user3758251 Missed the array? Seemed pretty obvious to me and others who agreed with me.